# No gateways are defined SMSlib

Tags: java, sms-gateway, smslib

I am trying to learn to use SMSlib to send sms using ZTE MF631 usb modem. Here is my code:

```
        Service.getInstance().startService();
        SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com5","COM5", 115200, "ZTE", "MF631");

        gateway.setInbound(true);
        gateway.setOutbound(true);
        gateway.setSimPin("0000");
        gateway.setSmscNumber("+9779800009000");

        try {

           Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
           OutboundMessage outboundMsg = new OutboundMessage("+9779843669921", "Hello there!");
           Service.getInstance().sendMessage(outboundMsg);
        } finally {
            gateway.stopGateway();
            Service.getInstance().removeGateway(gateway);
            Service.getInstance().stopService();
        }
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

```
org.smslib.SMSLibException: No gateways are defined.
    at org.smslib.Service.startService_Internal(Service.java:295)
    at org.smslib.Service.startService(Service.java:229)
    at org.smslib.Service.startService(Service.java:196)
    at com.mail.utility.SendSmsUtility.sendSMS(SendSmsUtility.java:10)
    at com.mail.action.SendSmsAction.sendSms(SendSmsAction.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing something like this before you start service:

```
Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
```

Here is [SMSlib example.](https://github.com/smslib/smslib-v3/blob/master/src/java/examples/modem/SendMessage.java)

Comment: I've updated the code with addGateway and removeGateway but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you try to move `Service.getInstance().startService();` after `addGateway(gateway)` line?